# MySql script to change and add values in a loop (not a procedure)

Tags: mysql

I need to iterate over a set of values, change a column value for each row but also execute two INSERT INTO queries for each row (i need a value from the rows).

All this must be done without a procedure but using a simple SQL script.

somethig like this:

1. select FROM table A all rows that fit a condition,
2. change column 'col1' value
3. insert into table B a record that points to A.col2.

Is it possible?

Regards,
Id

Comment: "without a procedure but using a simple SQL script".  What makes a stored procedure "non-simple" SQL?  In any case, the MySQL scripting language only supports control-flow (such as loops) within stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  So, you need a stored procedure to do what you want.

Comment: thanks..
Is there a way to achieve my goal using a complicated script with stuff like INSERT INTO (a,b,c) VALUES (x,t,SELECT B.id...)?

Comment: Yes, there is of course. Please have a try first and come back if you encounter any problems. SO is no code writing service. Meanwhile I'm voting to close as "too broad".